# downloading matplotlib python 2.7.1 windows 8

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, pip

I want to use pyPlot, therefore install matplotlib.
When I downloaded numpy, I realized I already have pip on this python version (I have windows 8, using 64-bit)..

Now if I want to install matplotlib to my python, can I do it using some kind of command from the command line or do I need to install something first and then navigate to setup.py Directory and run:

```
python setup.py
```

when I try:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

or even installing it and using

```
pip install matplotlib-1.5.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

it gives me error:

```
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: 2.7.9 |CUSTOM| (default, 
Jul1 2015 03:41:50 ) [ MSC vs. 1500 64 bit (AMD 64)]
```

location of my python is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7
```

ANY HELP..?

Comment: The location of python that you give is probably only a link to the real exe as this is only the start menu entry

Answer (score 1):

Why not installing it with `pip` then?

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Bcause it gives me error:

valueError:-failed-to-parse-cpython-sys-version-2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

You either install it with pip: `pip install matplotlib` or download the binary from windows.

Comment: Bcause it gives me error: valueError:-failed-to-parse-cpython-sys-version-2.7.9

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.4.3 there are the exe files, but if you're getting an error with pip, there's something wrong with your installation.

Comment: I've downloaded one of them, and tried installing it using whl.. still gives me same error